# How to make a sauce based on tea

Tags: sauce, tea

I have some pu-erh tea, and I love the smokiness of it. I was thinking about trying to incorporate it into a dish somehow. Specifically, I was thinking about using something like pacific cod. Then I could potentially create a sauce or a rub for it.

Any suggestions for how to incorporate the tea into a dish without losing it's smoky flavor?

Answer (score 10):

Interesting question. My first thought would be to try just poaching the fish in the tea. That should transfer more of the flavour than, say, steaming it. Google finds [this recipe](http://www.culinarycafe.com/Seafood-Fish/Green_Tea_Poached_Fish.html) where they use an unnamed green tea.

Comment: [Saved page](http://web.archive.org/web/20010408193637/http://www.culinarycafe.com/Seafood-Fish/Green_Tea_Poached_Fish.html), courtesy of Web.archive.org

Answer (score 7):

You could brew a very strong batch of the tea, and reduce that to the desired level.  You can use that as a base for a sauce to accompany the fish.

Answer (score 7):

Tea leaves are excellent for smoking. I have had green tea smoked duck, gorgeous. Earl Grey works beautifully in desserts.

Comment: ETA:I did a stage a year and a half ago at a restaurant where we made an orange pekoe gel, served with an almond cake and whipped honey.

Answer (score 5):

Good pu-erh tea is now often paired with chocolate, so a ganache might work nicely; simmer some cream with the tea leaves, strain into bittersweet chocolate while the cream is still near boiling, stir aggressively until smooth. A pu-erh and chocolate custard would likely work fairly nicely, or something along the lines of

Marbled tea eggs would probably also work well; this involves simmering pu-erh tea, soy sauce, sugar, and water together, often with star anise; cracking gently hard-boiled eggs all over, without breaking the shells off. Soak overnight in the solution and you should get a pretty nice aromatic and pre-seasoned boiled egg.

I suspect that pu-erh brewed with orange peels, then integrated into minced shallots cooked with butter, would work nicely together, though I'm not sure what the best candidate for the sauce would be; perhaps roasted pork or maybe some boiled udon.